# Rails 2: test 'link_to' and other view helpers from the rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In rails 2, I use the console a lot and was wondering what the best way to test view helpers such as 'link_to' or 'url_for' using it.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: The answers here are outdated. An answer for Rails 3 and 4 is http://stackoverflow.com/a/8832424

Answer (score 9, accepted):

just include the UrlWriter module in your console:

`include ActionController::UrlWriter`

Comment: I got `NameError: uninitialized constant ActionController::UrlWriter` .  I had to use `include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper`.  This is with Rails 3.2.22.2.

Comment: Looks like this module was deprecated in rails 3 (http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.9/ActionController/UrlWriter) . This answer was current for rails <= 3. For rails 3 + 4 use `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` and, without testing, I think you use `ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper` for rails 5.

Answer (score 17):

You can add your `include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper` to ~/.irbrc to auto load it when you start the console.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small addition. You will need to provide the host parameter too e.g

```
my_random_link_helper(:host => "www.google.com")
```